# screen brightness flickering

Tags: 11.10, brightness, flicker

After installing ubuntu 11.10 screen started flickering between two brightness levels i gues its not hardware issue because everything worked perfectly fine on windows which i have been using before ubuntu and ubuntu is installed within widows sometimes everything works fine but after suspending the screen of after screen goes iddle flickering starts again... soo any help would be apprichiated

Comment: could you post your output of this command: `lspci | grep -i vga` From your description, it seems to be a graphical driver problem. I've add the same problems with SiS drivers in the past.

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Robson CE [AMD Radeon HD 6300 Series]
im using Lenovo G570

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to disable the KMS of Radeon... See http://tomlowshang.blogspot.com/2010/04/disabling-radeon-kms.html and the comment

It works on my PC, HP ProBook 4421s, my graphical driver:

```
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Robson CE [AMD Radeon HD 6300 Series]
```